# Error while accessing admin section

Tags: 8, updating

I am facing the following error while trying to access Admin section in Drupal 8 (WAMP Server). I tried to install the `Update manager module` and from then I am facing this error. I am unable to access any Admin section of the website. But, I am able to login and access the User account section `(Ex: http/test.com/user/1)`.

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
>
> Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException: Route "update.report_update" does not exist. in `Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteProvider->getRouteByName()` (line 191 of core\lib\Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteProvider.php).

Any suggestion please?

Comment: Try running drush cr to rebuild the routes. If it is still not working see if the module is even stable. Maybe it is outdated and not ready for usage yet.

Comment: @IvanJaros, I will try the method which you poseted here, Thanks. 
While installing Drupal, I unchecked the "Check for updates" option. After that, I tried to install this "Update manager" module using the admin section where I faced the error. I will confirm if this is the cause by trying another Drupal installation.

Answer (score 0):

Its problem with my custom module. Wherever I am installing that module, it is creating a mess. I am trying to sort out the issue with my module.

This is due to the menu routing problem in my custom module. Please see the below link: https://www.drupal.org/node/2635308